# Andrew's experiments on CO2

Tags: pressure, volume

While studying  andrew's experiment  on CO2 i found a contradictory thing to my knowledge. At isothermal temperature  13.1°c as pressure increases volume decrease.  At a particular pressure CO2 starts liquifying and there is huge drop of volume.  But there no relative change in pressure at all. But PV should  constant.  Is this is contradictory to boyle's law?
If it is not contradictory then what happens here?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

PV is constant for an ideal gas. A gas that is liquefying is not ideal.